# python selenium script error : web element has no len

Tags: python-3.x, web, selenium-chromedriver

```
results= driver.find_element_by_class_name("cntanr")

print ("Found " + str(len(results)) + " searches:")
```

This is giving below **error:**

> object of type 'Web Element' has no len

Answer (score -1):

The function `driver.find_element_by_class_name(str)` returns a `WebElement` which is not iterable and thus not accepted by `len`.